# How to copy entries with 1-m relation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I modeled a Lawyer that can have *m* kinds of expertise.
My framework then generated these 3 tables:

1. Lawyer
2. lawyer_expertise_mm
3. Expertise

Example:

`Lawyer`:

```
id, name, email, expertises(amount)  
- 1, Joe, joe@joe.com, 2
```

`Expertise`:

```
id, name  
- 1, Employee rights
- 2, Information safety
```

`lawyer_expertise_mm` has those columns:

```
id_local(lawyer), id_foreign(expertise)  
- 1, 1
- 1, 2
```

Now I want to copy all lawyers and change their e-mails to one address to use for testing. The problem is after I do that all the copies don't have any expertise anymore because my sql only inserts the copies in the lawyer table:

```
INSERT INTO `Lawyer`
( `name`, `email`,`expertises`)
SELECT  `name`, "test@test.test",`expertises`
FROM Lawyer
```

I don't know how I can write an sql statement that also makes copies for the new lawyer's ids in the lawyer_expertise_mm.
So what I'll get is:

```
id, name, email, expertises
- 1, Joe, joe@joe.com, 2
- 2, Joe, test@test.test, 2
```

But what I'm missing is:

```
id_local(lawyer), id_foreign(expertise)  
- 1, 1
- 1, 2
- 2, 1
- 2, 2
```

So how can I achieve this? (It may not seem logical what I'm doing, but that's because I broke down my example to the basics of my question, I just wanna know if there's a nice way to do this which I don't know of yet)

I'm using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Without getting into a debate about autonum/identity columns, I presume your lawyer ids are an increasing series. Are names unique?

Comment: names aren't unique - but the id (of lawyer) is, every insert gets an increased id, yes

Comment: Well you can use a cursor. Otherwise you could make the names unique by temporarily appending the id to the end. (Probably use a zero=padded value.) But I'm looking at this closer and your tables don't make sense. `expertise` is in the wrong table.

Comment: so you mean it won't be possible if I generate new ids for each lawyer? ...I think I get your idea...could u tell me what doesn't make sense to you in particular, then I could explain it more in my question

Comment: You have many expertise per lawyer. The very reason you have the many to many table is so you can store it there.

Comment: yes, and I want to keep it that way...I just want to duplicate a lawyer, giving him a new id, but keeping his expertises

Comment: So you need to replicate those expertises as well. A cursor would let you loop. If this is a one-time thing you might consider the approach I'll post in an answer.

Comment: I didn't understand that last comment. And my apologies that I am stepping away from my computer very soon.

Comment: I also realized that you're keeping a count of the number of expertises. I misunderstood that as an id.

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as pseudo-code. I'm not sure I got all the MySQL functions/syntax right.

```
update Lawyer /* make the names unique */
set name = name + right('000000' + cast(id as varchar(6)), 6)

select max(id) from Lawyers /* use this value in the query below */

<copy lawyers here> /* copies will have the same name */

insert into lawyer_expertise_mm (id, expertise)
select l2.id, le.expertise
from
    Lawyer l1
    inner join lawyer_expertise_mm le
        on le.id_foreign = l1.id
    inner join Lawyer l2 /* link up the attorneys by range and name */
        on l1.id <= <max_id> and l2.id > <max_id> and l2.name = l1.name

update Lawyer /* revert to the original names */
set name = left(name, char_length(name) - 6)
```

Comment: ok, I will need a bit to understand and execute this in my real case - but I think you're on the right track to my solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a "temporary" column `origin_id` to store the original `id` when you duplicate the entries in the `Lawyer` table. You can then use it in a join to find and duplicate the related entries in the `lawyer_expertise_mm` table.

```
alter table Lawyer add column origin_id int default null;

INSERT INTO `Lawyer`
( `name`, `email`,`expertises`, origin_id)
SELECT  `name`, "test@test.test",`expertises`, id
FROM Lawyer;

insert into lawyer_expertise_mm
    select l.id, mm.id_foreign
    from lawyer_expertise_mm mm
    join Lawyer l on l.origin_id = mm.id_local;

alter table Lawyer drop column origin_id;
```

http://rextester.com/FURWK58495